# I tried to solve that Exercise 7.7.28 - Resnick Book.

Tags: probability-theory

**I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Resnick's book : I could only the first part. I need help with the second part.**

- Exercise $\mathbf{7.7.28}$.

Suppose $\{X_n, n \geq 1\}$ are uncorrelated random variables satisfying

$E(X_n) = \mu, \hspace{.22cm} Var(X_n) \leq C, \hspace{.22cm} Cov(X_i, X_j) = 0 , i \neq j$

**Show that as** $n \longrightarrow \infty$ that $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}} \longrightarrow \mu$ in probability and in $\mathit{L}2$}.

**So, my question is about this next part:**

**PART II**
**Now suppose** $E(X_n) = 0$ and $E(X_i,X_j) \leq \rho(i-j)$ for $i>j$ and $\rho(n) \longrightarrow 0$  as $n \longrightarrow \infty$. Show $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{X_i}{n}} \overset{P}\longrightarrow 0$  .

- **Solution Part I**
  By Theorem $\mathit{L}^2$ weak law}:
  Let $X_1 , X_2 , ...$ be random variables uncorrelated,
  com $E(X_i) = \mu$  e $Var(X_i ) \leq C < \infty$. Let $S_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$ implies when $n \longrightarrow \infty$,
  $\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}} \longrightarrow \mu$ in $\mathit{L}^2$ and in probability.

To show  $\mathit{L}^2$ converge, observe that $E\bigg(\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}}\bigg) = \mu$, thus

$E\bigg(\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu}\bigg)^2 = Var\bigg(\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}}\bigg) = \displaystyle{\frac{1}{n^2}}\bigg( Var(X_1) + ... + Var(X_n)   \bigg) \leq \displaystyle{\frac{C_n}{n^2}} $

How $n \longrightarrow \infty$, so $\displaystyle{\frac{C_n}{n^2}} \longrightarrow 0 $

Now consider the  following Lemma:

If $p > 0$ and $E(\vert Z_n \vert^p) \longrightarrow 0$ imply $Z_n \longrightarrow 0$ in probability.

So consider $Z_n = \displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}} - \mu$,

$$
And\bigg(\begin{vmatrix}  \displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}} -\mu \end{vmatrix}^p   \bigg) =  \displaystyle{\frac{1}{n}}E\bigg(\begin{vmatrix} S_n -\mu \end{vmatrix}^p   \bigg) = 0
$$

So $\displaystyle{\frac{S_n}{n}} \overset{P}\longrightarrow \mu$